# How do I write a graphQL mutation in a python function?

Tags: python, graphql

I want to create a python function of a simple graphQL mutation. I have a graphQL schema and there is a mutation to delete an object by giving its ID.
GraphQL docs shows :

```
delete(
id: ID!
): Boolean!
```

To delete the object using the global ID I tried creating a python function but I am getting a syntax error of graphQL which I am not able to figure out.

```
#function to delete FIB
def deleteObj(self,id): # returns FIB deletion boolean
    
        objDel = self.graphQLClient.fetch("""
            mutation delete($id: [ID!]!) {
                delete(id: $id,) {
                    id
                }
            }
        """, {
            'id': id ,
            
        })
        info('***Object deletion result %s\n' % objDel)
```

I am able to understand I am doing some silly mistake but an explanation would help me in the future.

Error I am getting is:

> fib deletion result {'data': None, 'errors': [{'message': 'Syntax
> Error GraphQL request (3:34) Unexpected empty IN {}\n\n2:
> mutation delete($id: [ID!]!) {\n3:                 delete(id: $id,)
> {\n                                    ^\n4:     \n', 'locations':
> [{'line': 3, 'column': 34}]}]}

I am able to insert an object using mutation something like this:

```
def insertFibEntry(self, prefix, name): # returns FIB entry ID
        
        fib = self.graphQLClient.fetch("""
            mutation insertFibEntry($name: Name!, $nexthops: [ID!]!) {
                insertFibEntry(name: $name, nexthops: $nexthops) {
                    id
                }
            }
        """, {
            'name': "/"+prefix ,
            'nexthops': [self.faces[name]['data']['createFace']['id']]
            
        })
        info('***fib result %s\n' % fib)
        info('***prefix is %s'% "'/"+prefix+"'"+ '\n')
```

Comment: are you interacting with a remote graphql api or are you implementing your own?

Comment: So I am using a docker image and this part is from that docker container so I dont know how they are implementing it but I was able to insert an entry with something like the new insert code I added in the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to the above question-

```
    #function to delete obj
def deleteObj(self,id): # returns obj deletion boolean
        
        objDel = self.graphQLClient.fetch("""
            mutation delete($id:ID!) {
                delete(id: $id)
            }
        """, {
            'id': id 
            
        })
        info('***fib deletion result %s\n' % objDel)
```